# Adding regex to an array in Perl

Tags: arrays, regex, perl, sum

I've just started using PERL for some scripting i'm doing, having never used it before, and I'm having some trouble getting some values into an array, and calculating the total.

I have a log file that i want to parse, and using a regex, pick up when certain values appear. i want these values added to an array, and then the total calculated at the end.
The file I'm trying to parse looks like

> ...completed_pop_count: 0 
>   ...uncompleted: 0 
>   CALL NEXT 
>   ...completed_pop_count: 2 
>   ...uncompleted: 0 
>   CALL NEXT 
>   ...completed_pop_count: 2 
>   ...uncompleted: 3 
>   CALL NEXT

....and carries on

This is what i have so far:

```
open (my $file, 'test.log');
while (<$file>){
   my @array = /.*completed_pop_count: (.*)$/;
   print @array;
}
close($file);
```

The output to this is like

> 022.....

To me this looks like all the values are in a single element of the array. However I need them to be on separate so that I can calculate the total sum.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add elements to array, use `push @arr, "element"`.

```
use List::Util qw(sum);

my @array;
while (<$file>){
   push @array, $1 if /.*completed_pop_count: (.*)$/;
}
print "@array\n";

print sum(@array), "\n";
```